# `pars` in haskell giving no speed up

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to learn about `pars` and `parseq` in haskell. I did the following:

```hs
import Control.Parallel
import System.Random

quicksort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
quicksort [] = []
quicksort (x : xs) = losort ++ x : hisort
  where
    losort = quicksort [y | y <- xs, y < x]
    hisort = quicksort [y | y <- xs, y >= x]

parallelQuicksort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
parallelQuicksort [] = []
parallelQuicksort (x : xs) =
  losort `par` (hisort `pseq` (losort ++ (x : hisort)))
  where
    losort = forceList' $ quicksort [y | y <- xs, y < x]
    hisort = forceList' $ quicksort [y | y <- xs, y >= x]

forceList' :: [a] -> [a]
forceList' xs = foldr pseq [] xs `pseq` xs

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let input = take 3000000 (randomRs (0, 10000) (mkStdGen 42)) :: [Int]
  print $ last $ parallelQuicksort input
```

However running `cabal run haskell-notes-exe -- +RTS -N1 -s` and `cabal run haskell-notes-exe -- +RTS -N2 -s` give around the same performance (in fact the `-N1` version is a bit faster). Why? How can I fix this? I'd have hoped that the `-N2` version would be rougly 2x as fast. (I'm aware there's better ways to sort, I just want to understand this).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure to build using the `-threaded` option.

```
executable haskell-notes-exe
  ghc-options: -threaded
```

With that I see `-N1` take 11s and `-N2` take 10s, so there is a noticeable speedup but they are still close enough that it can be hard to distinguish on a noisy machine.

Note the value of the first pivot, `head input = 8752`, from the range `(0,10000)`. So one thread is sorting only 12% of the list while the other has 88% of the list.

If we split the list roughly in half instead, `parallelQuicksort (5000 : input)`, `-N1` takes 9s, and `-N2` takes 6.5s. A bit better, although not a 2x speedup. The rest of this answer explains why that is.

Use the RTS option `-s` to print some runtime statistics. Focus on the table that lists times:

```
$ ... +RTS -N1 -s

  INIT    time    0.001s  (  0.001s elapsed)
  MUT     time    5.727s  (  5.785s elapsed)
  GC      time    3.273s  (  3.311s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.002s  (  0.004s elapsed)
  Total   time    9.003s  (  9.101s elapsed)


$ ... +RTS -N2 -s

  INIT    time    0.001s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  MUT     time    6.412s  (  3.350s elapsed)
  GC      time    4.229s  (  3.240s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.012s  (  0.010s elapsed)
  Total   time   10.654s  (  6.601s elapsed)
```

There are two time columns. The first is the CPU time, the sum of the times spent by each thread; the second is the "elapsed" time, the time you had to wait.

The two significant lines in each run are `MUT` and `GC`. `GC` is time spent in the garbage collector. `MUT` is short for "mutator", and you can deduce that's the time doing actual work.

Roughly half of the time is spent in the GC. Your program produces a lot of garbage. Almost all of the intermediate lists that are inputs and outputs to recursive calls of `quicksort` are thrown away, not contributing to the actual final list. You can avoid allocating useless intermediate output lists by using difference lists instead, but the input lists at every recursive call cannot really be avoided (that's why some consider that a true QuickSort is an in-place algorithm; Haskell lists are just the wrong data structure for that).

Note also that with `-N2`, in `MUT`, the elapsed time is about half the CPU time, confirming that the two threads are sharing the work. The two threads may still have uneven work: we put the first pivot in the middle, but the subsequent pivots may be off-center.

In contrast, the GC time is not shared evenly between threads. The garbage collector is only partially parallel. Another important bit to know is that it is a stop-the-world garbage collector: all threads must stop to let the GC run. This explains why `-N2` has a noticeably higher `MUT` CPU time than `-N1`: there is a lot of garbage, so the GC runs often, that interrupts the threads every time, causing a lot of overhead for synchronization.

To summarize, the two threads are indeed splitting the "real work" in half, but the GC adds extra work that is not parallelizable, and requires synchronization which further slows down the "real work".

Comment: A good finale of this wonderful post would be to show how using a more space-efficient sequence type than lists could improve things...

Comment: A mutable array seems like the only thing that would work. It could be fun to use linear types to make it look functional though.

Comment: Oh, maybe... I thought something that has more compact representation like an unboxed vector could be an improvement. But maybe with no streaming (that you get for free with lists) it will allocate too much.